# Why I am losing the content of my ArrayList when I switch from class to class?

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

I am currently having a problem and at the same time struggling about ArrayList. I am stuck when I use the ArrayList. I am working on a 3-layer program, which includes the Client, Directory and the Person Class. My code reads the content of a file and adds them into the ArrayList first, which works fine. After, at one point, when it keeps switching back and forth from either the Client or the other class, the content of the ArrayList is gone. When I try to print, for example, there's nothing to print anymore and so my problem comes in. Also, when only using a class and excluding the other classes, I don't have a problem manipulating the data when I hard code it and print it. To see a better picture of it, I have some of my codes below.

```
public class Client 
{

    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Directory print = new Directory();
        Directory loadList = new Directory();

        System.out.print("Please enter the file name: ");
        fileName = kb.nextLine();
        fileName = fileName + ".txt";
        inFile = new File(fileName);
        in = new Scanner(inFile);
        loadList.loadData(in);
        showMenu();

        System.out.println();

        selection = '\0';
        while(selection != 'E')
        {
            System.out.print("Please choose one of choices: ");
            choice = kb.next();

            selection = choice.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            switch(selection)
            {
                case 'P':
                    print.printDirectory();
                    break;
                case 'L':   
                    System.out.println("Search!");
                    break;
                //some codes here for selection process 
            }
        }

        System.out.println ("Thank you!");
    }
}
```

By the time I choose to print the content of my ArrayList, all of its content is gone. I am left only with the header and an empty list. I thought by making the ArrayList as an instance variable, it would work fine, but it didn't.

```
public class Directory
{

    private ArrayList<Person> directory = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
    }
    public void loadData(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String firstName, ini, lastName, dep, phoneNo;
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            fName = in.next();
            ini = in.next();
            lName = in.next();
            dep = in.next();
            phoneNo = in.next();

            Person personDetails = new Person(fName, ini, lName, dep, phoneNo;

            directory.add(personDetails);
        }   
    }
    public void printDirectory()
    {

        System.out.format("%s%28s%22s%n","Name","Department","Phone Number");
        for(Person dir: directory)
        {
            System.out.println(dir.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank in advanced if someone can further explain this to me. When I go back to the Client and invoking a method from the Directory class during the process selection from the menu, I loose of all my data from the ArrayList?

Comment: Where are you creating object of class Directory ?

Comment: @bakero98 the loadList.loadData(in) and the print.printDirectory(); are the Directory object.

Comment: Why are you creating 2 different Directory objects. Putting items in arraylist in one, and reading from another ?

Comment: @bakero98 I thought creating two instances of the Directory object would do the same process of adding the contents of the file into the ArrayList. Thus, I created two of them. I didn't know that I could just only use one object for it to work and without losing the data. By looking at the edited code below, it finally made sense. The dir object holds the content of the Directory class. By calling the dir object, it should still hold the values while the program is running. Thank you so much in helping me solve this problem.

Comment: @mre Err... I used the debugger. I normally use the debugger to fix some things in my programs. Honestly, this kind of programming is new to me

Comment: @ComradeStalin Every object for itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read from the same object where you put items in ArrayList

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Directory dir= new Directory();

    System.out.print("Please enter the file name: ");
    fileName = kb.nextLine();
    fileName = fileName + ".txt";
    inFile = new File(fileName);
    in = new Scanner(inFile);
    dir.loadData(in);
    showMenu();

    System.out.println();

    selection = '\0';
    while(selection != 'E')
    {
        System.out.print("Please choose one of choices: ");
        choice = kb.next();

        selection = choice.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        switch(selection)
        {
            case 'P':
                dir.printDirectory();
                break;
            case 'L':   
                System.out.println("Search!");
                break;
            //some codes here for selection process 
        }
    }

    System.out.println ("Thank you!");
}
```